# Stretch submenu to parent menu size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I am creating a horizontal dropdown menu with css and javascript. I have made the menu stretch to the width I want (956 px) and the menu options to spread out in this, but I don't know how to get the submenus as I want them. I want each one of them to have the same width as their parent. Anyone who can help me with this?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="nav">
  <div id="meny">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li class="dropmenu"><a href="#">Abcde</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropmenu"><a href="#">Fghijklmn</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropmenu"><a href="#">Shop</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#nav{
width: 956px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#meny{
display: table;
width: 100%;
border-collapse: collapse;
border: none;
}

#menu{
display: table-row;
list-style: none;
}

.dropmenu{
display: table-cell;
background-color: #ff5b2e;
}

.dropmenu a{
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
}

.submenu{
display: none;
list-style: none;
background: #ff5b2e;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
}

.submenu li{
width: 100%;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropmenu').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.submenu').slideToggle(); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I feel like this should be solvable without javascript. Here's what I did:

(1) Remove `position:absolute` from `.submenu` (is there a reason why you wanted it there?)

```
.submenu{
display: none;
list-style: none;
background: #CC0000;
padding: 0;
width: auto;
}
```

(2) Move the background-color from `.dropmenu` to `.dropmenu a`

```
.dropmenu a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
background-color: #ff5b2e;    
}
```

(3) Additionally, I noticed that when you hover over the submenu several times, the dropdown will toggle several times too. Note the `stop()` I added on this line on the js:

```
$(this).find('.submenu').stop().slideToggle();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ouz0q5Lj/1/

Comment: This seems to work good, but when I hover over my first option in the menu, the two following options move a little to the right. Nothing happens when I hover over the two others though... any idea why?

Comment: What browser are you using? I am not seeing that in my chrome browser

Comment: Firefox. I don't see it in Fiddle, but it seems to act different when I open it from my computer... very weird.

Comment: Hmm.. just tried to run in locally from my machine and use firefox. I can't replicate the issue :/ can't really help you there.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the word I originally use there instead of "Abcde" is only three characters long and then the width has to change when the submenu slides down because some words are longer there.

Comment: Gotcha. in that case I'm afraid you have to set an absolute width on `.dropmenu`. Since there are 3 items on the parent menu i set it to 33%, but if you want more items then you can adjust accordingly. see here: http://jsfiddle.net/ouz0q5Lj/2/. Otherwise I guess you either have to re-look at the way you coded the entire menu, or just go with the javascript option above (just remember to add the `stop()`!)

Answer (score 3):

Fixed here

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropmenu').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.submenu').toggle(); 
      var width = $(this).css('width'); // find width of sub menu
      $(this).find('.submenu').css('width', width); // set the width of drop down here
  });
});
```

You can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/yb2p8aoj/